# Converting between clause to joins

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2, postgresql-9.1

Need a generic sql query for joins that can run on mysql, postgres and other major DBs

I have a table named autumn4.ip , I have `three columns: id,start,end (all ints).`

How do I make a join so that I make use of BUT not by BETWEEN but by JOINS.

like pseudo:

```
select * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant >= start ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 1; +

select * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant <= end ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1;
```

how to some one join the above two queries to get one row of data that would be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number-constant BETWEEN START AND END LIMIT 1;
```

Just dont ask my why I am doing it :)
but I know you woudl so:

I am trying to accomplish is to use 2 indexes, start and end. if i use BETWEEN and/or a composite index of start,end. Only start index is used and not the end. now please dont tell me that I am wrong. I just want it that way. I have done alot of research on this

if i do create single indexes for both start and end, only one is used. give me a query in which both are used

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Shouldn't you have an index on `autumn4.ip.number`? Or is that just a constant and there's more to this query?

Comment: @user1336827 My assumption is "Why does this query take 30 seconds and what can I do to optimize it?" although I think there's more to the question and query here.

Comment: as bolded, i need a join based query. number is a figure, not a column name

Comment: How many results would there be without the `LIMIT 1`? How slow is it? BETWEEN should be optimized for index etc. A `UNION` would be slower (and have 2 results instead of 1).

Comment: it takes > 30 seconds. http://pastie.org/8577418

Comment: Can you give examples of what result data you need and the input data?

Comment: Some of us might not interpret the wording of your question the way you intended. You came here to learn how to do something.  Rather than fret over whether someone suggest an alternative you may not like, we can help you best if you explain the constraints on the problem. And remember that while you may have invested a good amount of time in your research (which we appreciate) there are people here with *decades* of experience working with databases, so it might be prudent to keep an open mind

Answer (score 0):

You want that the request selects only the 1st row between start and end, using JOINs ?

**EDIT:**

> forget my answer! No need for 2 tables for what I thought! It's more an index problem than anything else.....

You can try to put an index on START, and a different one on END (it seems that you have 1 index with both columns, don't you?), and do your select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number >= START AND :number <= END ORDER BY START LIMIT 1; 

(or ORDER BY START DESC if you want the biggest start) .
```

.

Comment: some how not working for me. heres a sample data http://pastie.org/8577418

Comment: Working for me with your model: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/609e0/2
Be careful: you should add a primary key on a column... here i considered the "loc_id" field was unique in the example

Comment: there is one catch. if you promise to guid me a little more.    select number >= start will result in many values, how about I fetch the max one.        then     select number <= end , how about i fetch the most min value..    Now I get my results. right?

Comment: Please add some information: which row do you want exactly?

Comment: ORDER BY would do fine too.   as because the number > start can have many rows fetch and number < end can have many rows. we want a tight range. so  MAX for first and min for second thing

Comment: Masood: my edit is in line with your question : no need of JOIN if you just need 1 row at the end (limit 1 => 1 row).

It will be different if you need 2 lines : 1 with the min start, 1 with the max end!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number >= START AND :number <= END`   is same as using `BETWEEN` under the hood

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more if you do not want to understand what we say (as said in the other subject you opened)

Answer (score 0):

What you have heard about range scans and `between` in MySQL is simply not true.  Here is a quote from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html):

> B-Tree Index Characteristics
>
> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that
>   use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators. The index also can be
>   used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string
>   that does not start with a wildcard character.

So, the use of an index is not surprising.  The best index for this data would be a composite index on `start, end`.

The problem that you have is that you have two columns `start` and `end`.  This makes the query a bit more complicated.

The following could conceivably perform better under some circumstances, with an index on `start` and a separate index on `end` and a primary key on the rows:

```
select gt.*
from (SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number >= start) gt join 
     (SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number <= end) lt
     on gt.PRIMARYKEY = lt.PRIMARYKEY;
```

Comment: Is it really useful to do 2 queries? WHERE condition 1 and condition 2 would be ok because he just wants 1 row at the end...

Comment: @NicolasR . . . It is generally not useful to do two queries where one would do.  The OP is explicitly asking for a `join` query (and there may be some strange circumstances where the `join` version would work better); I suspect this is out of ignorance of SQL.

Comment: I understand, that's also why my 1st response (edited now) was containing the same join that you made...
But if we can change his idea or help him explain why he absolutely wanted JOIN, that would be great no?

Comment: the query hung the db . replaced gt.PRIMARYKEY = lt.PRIMARYKEY; by gt.id = lt.id;