# How to use indexes for a query filtering BETWEEN two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, indexing

I need a generic sql query for joins that can run on mysql, postgres and other major DBs.

I have a table named `autumn4.ip` with three columns: `id, start, end` (all ints).

How do I make a join so that I make use of BUT not by BETWEEN but by JOINs?

Like (pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant >= start
ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant <= end
ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1;
```

How to join the above two queries to get the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM autumn4.ip WHERE :number-constant BETWEEN START AND END LIMIT 1;
```

I am trying to use 2 indexes on `start` and `end`. If I use BETWEEN and/or a composite index on `(start, end)`, only start index is used and not the end. now please don't tell me that I am wrong. I just want it that way. I have done a lot of research on this.

If I do create single indexes for both start and end, only one is used. I am looking for a query that uses both.

Comment: Please explain why you are not using the last query, which (apart from the limit 1) is standard SQL and supported by all the databases you mention.

Comment: I requested "Just dont ask my why I am doing it :)"

Comment: @MasoodAhmad then we can't helped you because we have to know what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting between clause to joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786851/converting-between-clause-to-joins)

Comment: I am trying to accomplish is to use 2 indexes, start and end. if i use BETWEEN and/or a composite index of start,end. Only start index is used and not the end. now please dont tell me that I am wrong. I just want it that way. I have done alot of research on this

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own previous question. Please don't post it twice. And why did you tag this question with so many database engines?

Comment: Create a single index on `start, end`, as recommended in an answer to your previous question.

Comment: if i do create single indexes for both start and end, only one is used. give me a query in which both are used

Comment: because there's one index consisting of two columns the term is called a composite key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks but having issues

Comment: the query hung the db . replaced gt.PRIMARYKEY = lt.PRIMARYKEY; by gt.id = lt.id;

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple

```
SELECT * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant >= start
ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM autumn.ip WHERE :number-constant <= end
ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1;
```

should work.

HOWEVER, let me question your research quality...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add the second column in a composite index in **`DESCENDING`** order.

Using a basic b-tree index, this would be used in **PostgreSQL** (if some general preconditions are met):

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON autumn.ip (col_start, col_end DESC)
```

The general principal should apply to any RDBMS with b-tree indices.

Also, for range queries like yours, a GiST index may be more effective in PostgreSQL. Consider this closely related answer:
[PostgreSQL index not used for query on range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407719/postgresql-index-not-used-for-query-on-range/14407839#14407839)

Aside: *Never* use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `start` or `end` as identifiers, especially if you are trying to stay compatible with multiple RDBMS.